# Complex, symmetric linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

What is the fastest numerical method to accurately solve complex, symmetric linear equations? Preferably, with a link to a Fortran code. The dimension is about 100-200 variables.

To be more explicit, we need to numerically solve $A x = B$, where $A$ is a $N\times N$ matrix, such that $A(i,j) = A(j,i)$ are complex numbers ($N \approx 200$).

Comment: What does it mean for complex equations to be "symmetric"?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: please see the question again, I edited it to add the answer to your question.

Comment: So, for example: would a matrix such as
$$
A = \pmatrix{1+i & 1+i\\1+i & 2}
$$
qualify as symmetric in this consideration?  I ask because it is unusual to talk about complex matrices in this way.  More often, people are interested in *Hermitian* complex matrices.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: yes, your example is symmetric. It is common in numerical analysis. For example:  http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/etemplates/node263.html